# Do not let create folder with certain names recorded in the array

Tags: php

I have a feature of compressing files on my website, and I use a method to unzip as well.

Now I have a problem, I cannot "create a folder" with certain names.

I need to use an array with some folder names, where those names could never create a folder

How can I do this?

```
$res = $zip->open('tmp/backup.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    echo 'ok';
    $zip->extractTo('../' . $folder_name);
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of names (eg censored words)

```
if (in_array($folder_name, $bad_words)) {
    //exit
    return false;
} else {
    //do the thing
}
```

Otherwise, if it's a OS thing, you'll likely want to use regex to either strip invalid characters or deny the operation.

This will require a bit more info, and you'll likely be able to google for a regex to your needs.